# Hive: create database fail with 'database already exists'

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a test suite which runs several spark unit tests. Each of these tests shares the same underlying spark context.
During the running of these tests I check if a db exists and if not I create it:

```
def dbExists(db: String) = spark.sql(s"show databases like '$db'").count > 0

if (!dbExists(db)) spark.sql(s"create database $db")
```

For some reasons, one of the tests is failing. Debugging I saw that for a certain db `dbExists(db)` returns false and the creation command fails with

```
ERROR RetryingHMSHandler:159 - AlreadyExistsException(message:Database db already exists)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_database(HiveMetaStore.java:891)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Everytime a test start, I clean the environment running `drop database db cascade` for each db that is not the default one.
The only explanation I can give is that some corrupted metadata is in the catalogue and spark sql thinks that the db exists, while it is not anymore.

The problem happens also inside a container with a fresh git clone of the project, meaning that it is not a previous run of the application that might pollute environment.

I run with hive support enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You are absolutely right, It is important to check the existence of the database before creation. This should work and would be much easier for the hive to check.

```
def dbExists(db: String) = spark.sql(s"show databases like '$db'").count > 0

spark.sql(s"create database if not exists $db")
```

This should work for you.